# Spi in interrupt mode for transmission and reception in PIC microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, communication, interrupts

I am using spi in pic16f877a, for m95320 eeprom. Using interrupt for communication, Everything is working fine. However I have to tweak something which is confusing me, of using interrupt.

```
#include<xc.h>
#include"spi.h"
unsigned char Data=0;//for recieve buffer
__bit bReady; /*just to acknowledge the interrupt*/
/*********************************/
void SPI_Master_Init(void)
{
  // Set SPI Mode To Master + Set SCK Rate To Fosc/4
  SSPM0 = 0; SSPM1 = 0; SSPM2 = 0; SSPM3 = 0;
  // Enable The Synchronous Serial Port
  SSPEN = 1;
  // Configure The Clock Polarity & Phase (SPI Mode Num. 1)
  CKP = 0;  //Idle state for clock is Low Level
  CKE = 0;  //Transition occure from low to active clock state.
  // Configure The Sampling Time (Let's make it at middle)
  SMP   = 0;    
  // Configure The IO Pins For SPI Master Mode
  TRISC5 = 0; // SDO -> Output
  TRISC4 = 1; // SDI -> Input
  TRISC3 = 0; // SCK -> Output
  TRISC2 = 0; // SS  -> Output
  RC2=1;    //Deselect the chip     
  /* Interrupts Are Needed */
  PEIE = 1; GIE = 1;
  SSPIE = 1;
  bReady=0;  
}
void clear_bit_ready(void){
    bReady=0;
}
__bit get_ready(void){
    return bReady;
}
/********************************************/
void spi_write(uint8_t  data){
    SSPBUF = data;  
    while(!get_ready());clear_bit_ready();
}
/*******************************************/
uint8_t spi_read(void){
    SSPBUF=Data;                /*write dummy data, just to initiate reception*/
    while(!get_ready());clear_bit_ready();  /*Avoid any collision*/
    return ((uint8_t)SSPBUF);       /*Useful Data*/
}
void SPI_Recieve_isr(void){
  if(SSPIF)
  {
    Data = SSPBUF;              /*Useless Data*/
    SSPIF = 0;
    bReady=1;
  }
}
```

Even though I have enabled the interrupt, I have to set a bit `bReady` to wait in both reception and transmission of data.
I have observed that even if I write data, interrupt is called, and same for reading. The actual data is received in `spi_read()` routine. In absence of the `bReady`, I don't get proper transmission/reception. It is again polling type of method, then what is the use of interrupt? I suspect data collision while writing and reading.
My question is :
Why I am supposed to wait for interrupt to finish the communication? Interrupt should take care of it.

Comment: With spi you're normally running a fairly high bit rate, so using interrupts makes little sense. Nevertheless, with spi you need to send something to receive something - you're not doing that. You isr reads the data that was clocked in, but you don't send something to clock the next byte in. You really only need one function for spi - pass it a byte to send and it returns the received byte.

Comment: How to know that which byte is our interested byte and which one  is useless data.

Comment: @Israr The protocol how you talk to EEPROM is defined in the EEPROM datasheet.

Comment: @Justme My major concern now is,  Is interrupt really profitable in terms of time complexity? or Poll method is ok.

Comment: @Israr It depends what other things your app needs to do simultaneously so you decide based on your requirements how you want to communicate with the EEPROM over SPI.

Comment: @Israr you know what speed you have configured the spi to and you know your processor speed. You can determine how many cpu clocks are used for each spi byte. Then how many clocks does it take to enter/exit the isr. The answer should be obvious.

Comment: Using interrupts to send and/or receive a single byte probably isn't particularly useful. But if you have a block of bytes to send/receive then you can configure your ISR to step to the next byte after the previous one completes. But where this really shines is if you have the interrupt trigger a DMA event to get/put bytes between the SPI module & RAM for the whole block.

Comment: @Kartman that is what I am doing in my `spi_read()` routine. To receive I send dummy data, then when interrupt gets called, I make `bReady` bit high and then read the SSPBUF, which is my useful/required byte. So I am waiting for that data to be ready and finish. This way I don't need to calculate the timing of reception /transmission. My only confusion still remain is even after calling the interrupt i have to poll that `bReady`, to complete the transfer.

Comment: Unlike other interrupt sources like Timers, we don't need to bother anything, just do other stuff, when timer overflows, interrupt come , then do isr() stuff and return back to where you are.

Comment: @brhans , is correct in this regard, that if we are facilitated with DMA , then and then only we can get rid of that polling, otherwise , interrupts also cant prevent polling. Interrupts are as same as polling method, where instead of `bReady` flag, wait in while loop for BF flag to reset.

Comment: brhans i don’t think PIC16 has the luxury of dma! @Israr, spi is not like uart - the send and receive are not separate. With spi you send a byte, then get a byte back. Forget interrupts for the moment and you don’t need bReady. Modify your spi_read() function to spi_xfer(uint8_t Data) . From your code the spi clock is fosc/4 so for 8 bits of spi, it takes 8 instruction times (if my ancient knowlege of PIC16 is correct ) so i’d expect using an interrupt will burn more time. Spi is very simple once you understand you need to send a byte to get a byte.

Comment: @Kartman, Ok , polling method will not take too much of time to transfer data. Is that what you want to say. I have to poll BF bit for transfer.

Comment: Yes. You will need to poll the SSP finished bit (i do not know what it is a actually  called without reading the datasheet).

Comment: It is called BF [buffer Full].

Comment: @Israr, no that's not how you should be using interrupts without DMA - you don't wait in a while loop looking at the interrupt flag - that's silly. You configure your interrupts & start the SPI transaction and then allow your code to go and do something else useful. When the interrupt occurs, the MCU jumps to your interrupt handler, and the interrupt handler code then starts the next byte of the SPI transaction, before allowing the MCU to return back to whatever is was doing.

Comment: @brhans, that is what I was doing. But there was data collisions, so I have to wait for that interrupt to finish and then go for the next transaction. And that is my confusion regarding the interrupt. `bReady` is nothing but letting me finish the interrupt, this way it is doing fine. But again it should not be the way.